# Putting a VerticalSlider into Mathematica's Manipulate?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do you set up manipulate so that you can control a variable with a vertical slider instead of a horizontal slider in Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the help  ....

```
Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1, ImageSize -> Small}, 
 ControlType -> VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I thought! I am trying to use webMathematica though and and I having difficultly getting the MSPManipulate function to display correctly. It will not create a vertical slider whenever I have tried thus far. Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: @Zack Sorry, no experience with webMma :(

Comment: Ehhh you win some you lose some. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: @Zack I suggest posting another question specifying WebMma! Someone else could help you!

Comment: Thanks! Actually another option has come up that no longer dictates the use of webMathematica.

Comment: @MikaIke `Manipulate[{u, v}, Row[{Control[{u, 0, 1}], Control[{v, 0, 1}]}], ControlType -> VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Left]`

Comment: @belisarius Thank you, Exactly what I want.... :-) You save me a questsion :-) because I was trying anipulate[
 Row[{u*v*w}], {u, 0, 8, ImageSize -> Small}, {v, 0, 8, 
  ImageSize -> Small}, {u, 0, 8, ImageSize -> Small}, 
 ControlType -> VerticalSlider, ControlPlacement -> Up]

and I can´t reach to vertical sliders in a Row.  Mathematica is a little rare sometimes... but... stackoverflow colleagues is... fantastic!

Comment: Any idea how I might add a display of the numercal value of the manipulated variable? For a vertical slider Appearance -> Labeled does not work inside the iterator. I look for something similar to it.

Comment: One might combine a vertical slider and a display of its numerical value using functions one level below Manipulate: e.g.     Panel[Row[{Column[{VerticalSlider[Dynamic[x]], Dynamic[x]}],  Dynamic[Plot[Sin[10 y x], {y, 0, 2 Pi}]]}]].  (n.b.: how do I mark the code here as code?)