# Circular/Angular slider

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

A [recent SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4418699/421225) reminded me of some code I tried to write a while back. The aim is to make a `CircularSlider[]` object that can be used for angle-like variables in dynamic objects.

The framework for my solution (below) comes from the `ValueThumbSlider[]` defined in the [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html#441733133) tutorial.  The main difference is that in `ValueThumbSlider[]` the value of the slider and the position of the `LocatorPlane[]` are the same thing, whilst in my `CircularSlider[]` they are not - and this leads to problems.

The first problem is that moving the [`Locator`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Locator.html) will not change the slider value. This is fixed by using the 2nd argument in the [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html): `(x = #/Abs[Complex @@ #]) &`.

This in turn leads to the problem that if you externally set the value of the slider (`t`) from outside, it will immediately revert to its previous value. This is fixed by keeping the old value (`t0`) and comparing to `t`. If they don't match then it's assumed that t has changed and so the `Locator` position `x` is updated to its new position.

```
CircularSlider[t_] := CircularSlider[t, {0, 1}];
CircularSlider[Dynamic[t_], {min_, max_}] /; max > min := 
 With[{d = (max - min)/(2. Pi)},
  DynamicModule[{td = t/d, x, t0}, x = {Cos[td], Sin[td]};
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[If[!NumberQ[t], t = min; x = {Cos[td], Sin[td]}];
     If[t != t0, t0 = t; x = {Cos[td], Sin[td]}];
     t = Mod[Arg[Complex @@ x] d, max, min]; t0 = t;
     x, (x = #/Abs[Complex @@ #]) &],
    Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Circle[], 
      Dynamic[{Text[NumberForm[t, {3, 2}], {0, 0}]}]}],
    ImageSize -> Small]]]
```

[image]

---

So my question is: can someone make this work with out the above kludges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for problem#1, I wouldn't consider the use of the second argument to `Dynamic` as a kludge -- that is what the second argument is for.  Therefore, I don't have an alternative solution for that one.

Problem #2 can be avoided if you refrain from assigning `t` in the first argument to `Dynamic`.

With this in mind, here is another implementation:

```
CircularSlider2[Dynamic[t_], r:{min_, max_}:{0, 1}] :=
  DynamicModule[{scale, toXY, fromXY},
      scale = (max - min) / (2. Pi);
      toXY[a_?NumberQ] := Through@{Cos, Sin}[a / scale];
      toXY[a_] := {1, 0};
      fromXY[{x_, y_}] := Mod[Arg[x + I y] scale, max, min];
      LocatorPane[
        Dynamic[toXY[t], (t = fromXY[#])&],
        Graphics[{
            AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Circle[],
            Dynamic[{Text[NumberForm[t, {3,2}], {0, 0}]}]
          }],
        ImageSize -> Small
      ]
  ]
```

The only material difference between this version and the original version is that the first argument to `Dynamic` is an expresssion that is free of side-effects.

---

### Edit

I just stumbled across this undocumented experimental feature in Mathematica 8:

```
DynamicModule[{x = RandomReal[{0, 50}]},
  {Experimental`AngularSlider[Dynamic@x], Dynamic@x}
]
```

[image: angular slider]

Comment: I like it! It doesn't suffer from the other problem I just noticed in my code, which is that you can't have 2 linked copies of a slider.

Comment: I like the `ShowWinding->True` option -- that's a really nice idea.

Comment: It is still experimental in Mathematica 13.2.