# Is this a bug in Control[] when combined with InputField[]?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So that you don't have to read all of the below, the crux of the matter was when using custom controls in `Control` or `Manipulate`, you have to use [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html).
As WReach pointed out, this is hidden in the [Manipulate documentation at the end of Scope, Controls](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html#ESS_2_).

So defining a function like `inField[x_Dynamic]` below is fine, so long as it's passed to `Control[]` as the pure function `inField[##]&`.

The confusing aspect of this question was that my `inField` was a customized `InputField`. And, as pointed out by joebolte, `InputField` is the default fall-back position of `Control` if it's given a nonsensical function. It does this without any warning, making the debugging a little tricky.

---

### Original Question (slightly modified to address WReach's 1st point)

Let's define a custom `InputField[]`

```
inField[Dynamic[x_]] := InputField[Dynamic[x], Expression, FieldSize -> 5]
```

Then use it in a `Manipulate[]` command

```
Manipulate[Table[{h, i, j, k}^n, {n, 1, 5}] // TableForm,
 {{h, 1, "hhh"}, inField},
 {{i, 1, "iii"}, inField[#] &},
 {{j, 2, "jjj"}, InputField[#, Expression, FieldSize -> 5] &}, 
 {{k, 3, "kkk"}, InputField[#, Expression, FieldSize -> 20] &},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Manipulate]

Note this problem does not occur when `inField[]` is called by itself
[image: inFields]

but does when `Control[]` is used (which is implicit in the `Manipulate` construction)
[image: Controls]

My question is: Why does the `Control`er wtih `inField` different to `inField[#]&`?
Is there an underlying reason or is it a bug?
This behaviour occurs in Mathematica 7 and 8.

---

**Edit:** My motivation for wanting a custom `inField` is to catch and correct user inputs - more than just the validation than `InputField` provides. E.g.

```
inFieldRat[Dynamic[var_]] := Dynamic[If[TrueQ[Element[N[var] // Chop, Reals]], 
       var = Rationalize[var, .05], var = Null, var = Null]; 
       InputField[Dynamic[var], Expression, FieldSize -> 5]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your definition of `inField` as follows:

```
Clear@inField
inField[x_Dynamic] := InputField[x, Expression, FieldSize -> 5]
```

The original definition was stripping the `Dynamic` wrapper from the argument, causing it to be evaluated immediately and remain constant thereafter.

I suspect that the observed behaviour differences are due to non-standard evaluation in `Control` (which is `HoldFirst`).

**Responding to @Simon's Comment**

My misunderstanding: I was addressing the problem where the control was not updating its value correctly, as opposed to the visual disparity.

The documentation for `Manipulate` states that the function must be a pure function (under *Scope*, *Controls*).  The documentation for `Control` is silent on the matter, but presumably it is the same since `Manipulate` is built upon `Control`.  `Control[{h, inField}]` is not a valid form.  However, Mathematica is not issuing an error message in this case.  Rather, it is simply ignoring `inField` altogether and acting as if `Control[{h}]` had been specified.  I would call this a bug.

I suspect that `Control` demands a pure function because a symbol has ambiguous meaning.  Should it use the down-values or the own-values of the symbol (or even the up-values)?  WRI apparently has gone for the `own-values` answer.  I still think a message is justified if the expression evaluates to something not understood by `Control`.

Comment: +1 sounds probable. Not sure how to verify the stripping of Dynamic!

Comment: That doesn't work. It produces identical outputs to the original `inField`. i.e. compare `Control[{h, inField}]` with `Control[{h, inField[#] &}]`, which naively should be the same.

Comment: (@belisarius: I like your +1 which doesn't actually signify an upvote!)

Comment: I missed that part in the `Manipulate` documentation. I agree, a warning message is definitely warranted. The problem I stumbled across was even more confusing since, as @joebolte said, `InputField` is the default fall-back behaviour.

Comment: I'm still not sure why `inField[x_Dynamic]` works but `inField[Dynamic[x_]]` doesn't. The latter construction was used in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420967/circular-angular-slider) and the Advanced Manipulate Functionality tutorial linked within...

Comment: @Simon ... just forgot. Fixed now :D

Comment: @Simon: the original definition of `inField` used `InputField[x...` instead of `InputField[Dynamic@x...]`.  `x_Dynamic` is an equivalent way to express the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just an observation

`Control` and `Manipulate` are masking whatever happens inside `InputField`, syntax errors included.

Try this nonsensical construct:

```
Control[{h, InputField[1, 1, 1, 1, pp -> 1, , FieldSize -> MyError]}]
```

Comment: You're right, but I'm providing inField as a function, while your example above is giving InputField[...] to Control as an Expression. It's probably a related behaviour. I think that your example *should* yield an error - as the dynamical variable `h` is not getting passed properly.

Comment: @Simon My intention was just showing that something fishy is going on inside Control and Manipulate. I started testing your case, and reducing it to it's more "elemental" expression, just to see if somewhere in the middle the problem disappeared. But it is still there, using just Control and InputField, and what is more, many other features of InputField (like syntax validation!) do not work either.

Comment: I understand, but I still think that my example should work, whilst yours should give an error. So, do you think that it's a bug or a feature?

Comment: @Simon As I understand it, a syntax error is a ... syntax error, no matter how deep you shove, it should be reported. I vote for bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is somewhat confused because InputField is what Control returns when the domain doesn't evaluate to anything sensible. Consider `Control[{h, z}]` (where z is undefined) as an even more striking version of belisarius's example.

`inField2 = Function[{x}, InputField[x, Expression, FieldSize -> 5]]`

works correctly, though if you just want to set the size of the input field, I recommend

`Manipulate[x,
 {{x, 5, "x"}, InputField, FieldSize -> 5}
 ]`

Edit: If you want a Manipulate that can dynamically reset its own variables, as your edit indicates, I recommend something like

`Manipulate[
 If[x < 5, x = 5];
 x,
 {x, 0, 10, InputField}
 ]`

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to SO (I've noticed a few WRI employees recently). Your first point is a very good one. Which explains what was going on in belisarius's examples - and why they don't produce errors. I've edited my question to give motivation.