# How can one get a list of Mathematica's built-in global rewrite rules?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I understand that over a thousand built-in rewrite rules in Mathematica populate the global rules table by default. Is there any way to get Mathematica to give a full or even partial list of those rules?

Comment: Do you mean like Options? To see all the options for a notebook you can do `Options[Notebook]` and it will give you all the options for a notebook. You can do this with any object. Is this what you mean by rewrite rules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is to get a job at [Wolfram Research](http://www.wolfram.com/company/opportunities/).

Failing that, I think that for things not completely compiled into the kernel you can recover most of the rules/definitions.  Look at

```
Attributes[fn]
```

where `fn` is the command that you're interested in. If it returns

```
{Protected, ReadProtected}
```

then there's something you can get a look at (although often it's just a `MakeBoxes` (formatting) definition or a AutoLoad/Stub type definition). To see what's there run

```
Unprotect[fn];
ClearAttributes[fn, ReadProtected];
??fn
```

Quite often you'll have to run an example of the command to load it if it was a stub. You'll also have to dig down from the user-facing commands to the back-end implementations.
Eventually you'll most likely reach a core command that is compiled into the kernel that you can not see the details of.

I previously mentioned this in [tips for creating Graph diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091728/tips-for-creating-graph-diagrams/4092955#4092955) and it got a mention in [What is in your Mathematica tool bag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4198961/421225).

An good example, with a nice bite-sized and digestible bit of code is `` Experimental`AngularSlider[] `` mentioned in [Circular/Angular slider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4420967/421225). I'll leave it up to you to look at the code produced.

Another example is something like `BoxWhiskerChart`, where you need to call it once in order to load all of the code. Then you see that `BoxWhiskerChart` proceeds to call `` Charting`iBoxWhiskerChart `` which you'll have to unprotect to look at, etc...

Comment: I should mention, that most of the really interesting rules  (stuff that represents propriety information) that Mathematica is known for, such as integration and summation rules are not accessible.

Comment: It's possible to get the source of some built-ins this way, but the code that's output is usually an unreadable mess (mostly because of the prepended contexts and lack of indentation).  What do you usually use to make it more readable?

Comment: @Szabolcs: Adding the contexts to your `$ContextPath` helps the first problem. Then copying the code into a new input cell helps somewhat with the 2nd problem.

Comment: `Begin[]` and `End[]` are good for that.  Would be nice to have a function that prints all relevant info with most common contexts automatically stripped.